# Check if ok has been clicked on infobox

Tags: python, tkinter

So I have a simple `showinfo` and i'd like to print something to the console when the ok button is clicked. I know you'd do it like this with an `askyesno` box.

```
def show_warning(self):
    self.startbutton.config(state="active")
    message_box = messagebox.askyesno("Break reminder","Remember, your breaks should ideally be between 3-5 minutes.")
    if message_box == 'yes':
        print("Yes clicked")
    else:
        print("No clicked")
```

How can I do it when the messagebox is `showinfo()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `showinfo()` infobox will only allow the user to continue with the tk application once they've closed the dialog box. You can use this to determine whether or not they clicked 'ok', much like `askyesno()`:

```
def show_warning(self):
    self.startbutton.config(state="active")
    Msg = "Remember, your breaks should ideally be between 3-5 minutes."
    if messagebox.showinfo("Break reminder", Msg):
        print("Ok clicked")
#rest of the program can now continue
```

i.e. there is no need to check for if they do not click 'ok'